# What is the difference between the different returns in nginx?

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https

So I am trying to redirect all of the http requests to https and my code looks as follows:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen 80;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
```

I read that it is better to redirect by using return and not rewrite. I am using `return 302`, because I read it is a non permanent redirect, whereas `return 301` is permanent and it will be saved in the cache meaning that every time I try to access `http://localhost` even with a different nginx configuration I will get redirected to `https://localhost` until I clean my cache. I read the documentation, however, I did not understand much and from the looks of it there are 2 more options:

```
For a code in the 3xx series, the url parameter defines the new (rewritten) URL.

return (301 | 302 | 303 | 307) url;
```

So what is the purpose of 303 and 307? I tried using 307 and it made 0 difference to 302.

Comment: [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) might help.

Comment: I still do not see a scenario, where I'd use 307 over 302 or I'd even have to use 303.

Comment: It is only significant if you need to redirect a POST request method, without breaking it.